# how to make joomla configuration xml

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I searched internet and didn't find anything that explained it clearly.

I want to create configuration to my component and to module but don't know where to start or how to start, if any1 knows good tutorial that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you will need for Joomla 2.5 as requested. Some fields are optional, such as the SQL and install/uninstall fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <extension type="component" version="2.5.0" methos="update">
        <name>Hello World</name>
        <creationDate>2007-01-17</creationDate>
        <author>John Doe</author>
        <authorEmail>example@example.org</authorEmail>
        <authorUrl>http://www.example.org</authorUrl>
        <copyright>Copyright Info</copyright>
        <license>License Info with link</license>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <downloadUrl>http://www.example.org/downloads/myjoomlaextensions/</downloadUrl>

        <installfile>install.helloworld.php</installfile>

        <uninstallfile>uninstall.helloworld.php</uninstallfile>

        <install>
            <sql>
                <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
                <file driver="mysql">install.mysql.nonutf8.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </install>

        <uninstall>
            <sql>
                <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
                <file driver="mysql">uninstall.mysql.nonutf8.sql</file>
            </sql>
        </uninstall>

        <files>
            <filename>index.html</filename>
            <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
            <folder>views</folder>
    </files>

    <languages>
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_test.ini</language>
            <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_test.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>

    <administration>

            <menu img="components/com_helloworld/images/helloworld_icon.png">Hello World</menu>
            <submenu>
                    <menu link="option=com_helloworld&amp;controller=config">Configuration</menu>
                    <menu img="icon" task="hello" controller="z" view="a" layout="b" sub="c">Hello Again!</menu>
                    <menu view="test" layout="foo">Testing Foo Layout</menu>
            </submenu>

            <files folder="admin">
                    <filename>index.html</filename>
                    <filename>admin.helloworld.php</filename>
            </files>

            <languages folder="admin">
                    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_helloworld.ini</language>
                    <language tag="en-GB">en-GB.com_helloworld.sys.ini</language>
            </languages>

    </administration>    
</extension>
```